# Calculator button no longer works

Tags: keyboard

I recently re-installed Windows 7 on my laptop, and although Windows recognizes my USB keyboard, the calculator button no longer opens the calculator. The volume buttons also no longer work. These keys worked on my prior installation of Windows 7.  Also, I do not have any particular software installed, and I never have. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What make and model is your USB keyboard?

Comment: My first thought is that you may have had custom keyboard drivers installed before that you didn't know about. Have you checked the manufacturer's website?

Comment: It's a Logitech S20. When I purchased it, I couldn't find drivers for it on Logitech's website, so I asked. Logitech informed me that is no need to install anything with that particular model.

Comment: I connected the keyboard on another computer, and the button works just fine. So, I'm not sure what's different with my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out .. the "Human Interface Device Access" service was disabled.

Comment: My Lenovo USB keyboard's media buttons didn't work after re-installing Windows 8 Pro. Enabling that service worked! Thanks!